# Modify cd tab autocompletion to show like ls -la

Tags: bash, macos, command-line-interface, oh-my-zsh

In a file structure like:

> |-/
>  |-foo
>  |--bar1
>  |--bar2
>  |--bar3.txt

Being at the `/` level and typing `cd f` followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> I see this:

> ~ / cd foo
>  /bar1 /bar2

Since I use oh-my-zsh, I can then navigate between all options with <kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> and select a directory. Is there a way to modify my bash profile, to make it produce a "list-like" output similar to the one I get from `ls -l`, so I have all options listed vertically instead of horizontally?

Expected (after `cd f` + <kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>):

> ~ / cd foo/ 
>  
>   drwxr-xr-x  22 admin  home   748 Feb  3 15:19 bar1 
>   drwxr-xr-x  16 admin  home   544 Feb  3 15:19 bar2

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable this behavior by using the `file-list` completion style. Just add the following line to your `~/.zshrc`:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' file-list all
```

With *Oh-My-Zsh* it might be necessary to add the line after sourcing `oh-my-zsh.sh`. Alternatively you can put a file with extension `.zsh` and the above line as content into `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom`.

Comment: That was exactly was I was looking for. The `zstyle` in the `~/.zshrc` did the trick. Thanks a lot!